# Equation of two periodic functions - How do you find A, ω and φ for the second function

Tags: trigonometry

I found the following question and wonder what the subject of this material is called and how you actually solve that (what method do you use?). I can't seem to find the name anywhere even though I have been searching.

---

If you are given

[image]

and

[image]

how do you find $A_2$, $ω_2$ and $φ_2$ so that the function $f_2(t)$ can be written on the following form:
[image]

---

### **EDIT:** Another example look like this:

Find the constants $A_1$, $ω_1$ and $φ_1$ so the following is satisfied:

### [image]

Comment: Can't see how $f_1(t)$ would be used in answer.

Comment: @coffeemath 
What about the 2nd example, does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to use trigonometric identities to get a new expression for your function.

**Hint:**

We have
$$
\forall t, f_2(t) = 5 \times \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t + \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}) = 5 \times \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t + \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{2})
$$